# Cannot download file when using Chrome on an iOS device

Tags: ios, file, google-chrome, download, blob

I am working on an Angular application which connects with a Web Api to download files as a Blob. The files get downloaded fine on all mobile devices with the exception of an **iOS device only when using a Chrome browser**. FYI, the files get downloaded fine when using the Safari browser on an iOS device.

Inside the WebApi I am setting the **Content-Disposition** header to "**attachment**", and setting the **filename** to the appropriate value, as below:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "test.pdf";
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

On the Angular side (front-end), I have tried **two options**:

- Option-1:
  Read the file using the **FileReader**, **dynamically create a hyperlink** with the href attribute set to the blob and the download property set to the filename, as below:

```
fetch(
    apiUrl, {
    method: 'get'
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.prepareFile(reader.result, fileName);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

- Option-2:
  Fetch the file from the web api, **create a blob** object, and use the **FileSaver.js** library (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save the file, as below:

```
fetch(
    apiUrl, {
    method: 'get'
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blobContent => {
    blob = new Blob([blobContent], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(blob, 'test.pdf'); //using FileSaver.js library
});
```

In Option-1, when using Chrome on iOS, the file downloads as **"document" without any file extension.**

In Option-2, when using Chrome on iOS, the file opens in Chrome, but when clicking on the "Open In" link in the browser, it displays the following **"The file could not be downloaded at this time."**

I would love to have any feedback, on the code above, or any work-arounds to download files when using Chrome on an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 that you mentioned about file getting downloaded with the name "document' is an existing issue on chrome on ios
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1252380